# AIX list size of files in a Volume Group

Tags: aix

I'm trying to list the size of all files on a volume group in AIX 5.3. I need to backup a volume group and I need to determine if it will fit on the tapes I have available.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/209072/list-all-physical-volumes-associated-to-a-volume-group) lists 'pvdisplay' and 'pvs' which aren't available in AIX it seems.

Comment: pvdisplay and friends are LVM commands, and AIX is not Linux. I think this question should be migrated to serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

`lsvg -p <volume group>` will list the volumes in a volume group (and sizes)
`lsvg -l <volume group>` will list the logical volumes (and file systems)

To add up file sizes I think you need to look at the file system (`du` command)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'lsvgfs' command against your volume group, and then sum the Used column from 'df' for those filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to use a script to make it easier 
[See this post about managing disk space in AIX](http://poweritpro.com/aix/breaking-down-your-aix-disk-usage)

The following script will show the space available for each volume group in AIX

```
printf "Volume Group Name     Total(MB)  Free(MB)   Used(MB)\n"; for vg in `lsvg -o`; do printf "%-18s" $vg; lsvg $vg | perl -nle 'printf "%-11s", $2 if /.*(TOTAL|FREE|USED) PPs:\s+\d+\s+\((\d+) meg.*/'; echo; done | awk '{total+=$2; free+=$3; used+=$4} {print} END{printf "---------\nTotals:           %-10s %-10s %-10s\n", total, free, used}'
```

this will display

> ```
> Volume Group Name     Total(MB)  Free(MB)   Used(MB)
> appvg             736        132        604      
> datavg            424        52         372      
> testvg            368        4          364      
> rootvg            20448      6784       13664    
> ---------
> Totals:           21976      6972       15004
> ```